# Vagrantfile check to see if a variable has been defined in .vagrantuser

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I am using Vagrant 1.4.2 with the [Nugrant plug-in](https://github.com/maoueh/nugrant) 1.4.1 on OS X 10.9. In my `.vagrantfile`, I have the following:

```
myvar:
  a: 'hello'
```

I can access the value of `a` in `Vagrantfile` like this:

```
puts "* The value of config.user.myvar.a is %s." % [config.user.myvar.a]
```

And the above code prints the following when I issue `vagrant up`:

```
* The value of config.user.myvar.a is hello.
```

However, I want to make setting `a` optional, so I added a Ruby `defined?` check to see if `config.user.myvar.a` has been defined. For illustrative purposes, I left the original `puts` command intact:

```
if defined? (config.user.myvar.a)
   puts "* config.user.myvar.a EXISTS (%s)" % [config.user.myvar.a]
else
   puts "* config.user.myvar.a DOES NOT EXIST"
end
puts "* The value of config.user.myvar.a is %s." % [config.user.myvar.a]
```

This outputs the following contradiction:

```
* config.user.myvar.a DOES NOT EXIST
* The value of config.user.myvar.a is hello.
```

Why is it that I can print the value of `config.user.myvar.a`, but not detect it with `defined?`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that plugin, but it seems to use Ruby's `method_missing` for fetching the config key from a Hash, but it doesn't define `respond_to?` method. So `define?` doesn't work correctly.

Instead there seems to be `has?` method, so you could try:

```
if config.user.myvar.has?(:a)
```

Or as the value will be `nil` if not set:

```
if !config.user.myvar.a.nil?
```

Comment: Sadly, neither suggestion works when `myvar.a` is not defined, because `myvar` is not found, resulting in a Nugrant error about `myvar` not  being found. I tried `if config.user.has?('myvar')` and `if !config.user.myvar.nil?` but even they did not work. But you may be onto something when you say that it may be a problem with the Nugrant plug-in. I will contact the author. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You were on the right track. Version 1.4.2 of the Nugrant plug-in fixes this specific issue. I'm using Version 1.4.1. See the bug report at https://github.com/maoueh/nugrant/issues/15

Comment: Should have used Symbol instead of String for `has?`. Edited the answer. And sure, you need to verify each level.

Answer (score 0):

With *tmatilai*'s input, I discovered that the problem occurs because the Nugrant plug-in does not support Ruby's `define?`. Other people have had [similar problems using `has?` with version 1.4.1 of the Nugrant plug-in](https://github.com/maoueh/nugrant/issues/15), which was fixed in version 1.4.2.

I upgraded to Nugrant 1.4.2, and found that checking for `myvar` with `if config.user.has?(:myvar)` now works correctly, but checking for `myvar.a` with `if defined?(config.user.myvar.a)` or `if config.user.myvar.has?(:a)` causes an undefined method error when `myvar.a` has not been defined. Not being a Ruby programmer, I decided to change strategy and simply flatten my structure in `.vagrantuser` to:

```
myvar_a: 'hello'
myvar_b: 'hallo'
```

Instead of:

```
myvar:
   a: 'hello'
   b: 'hallo'
```

Now I just check for `myvar_a` or `myvar_b` with:

```
if config.user.has?(:myvar_a) 
  puts "* config.user.myvar_a is defined: %s" % [config.user.myvar_a]
else
 puts "* config.user.myvar_a is NOT defined."
end
```

This is an acceptable work-around.